# JClouds: Is there a portable way to create a group of nodes that would intelligently distribute nodes in all locations?

Tags: jclouds

I was trying to find out if there is a way to create a group of nodes so that they are distributed across all locations:

```
//It would be helpful if there was a parameter to the function call that would give
//a hint to allocate nodes across all AZs or an option through the template 
groupNodes = computeService.createNodesInGroup("mygroup", 2, template);
```

This would be a nice feature for a cloud developer to ensure he has some nodes in each AZ to make his application continue to run even if a single AZ goes down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

While I understand what you're getting at. Practically speaking, you typically need to know where your instances are starting so you can get a location and id to refer to them later. If you'd like to discuss it further, I invite you over to the [jclouds-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/jclouds-dev) group.